# I want to extract the content of p tags with xpath. What should I do？

Tags: python, xpath, web-crawler

I want to extract the contents of all the p[@class="article"] tags under div[@class="content"].How should I write an XPath?It is worth mentioning that there is more than one div[@class="content"] tag. I would appreciate it if you could solve my problem.[image]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

And my code as fellows：

```
target_url = f' gongyi.qq.com/succor/detail.htm?id=12857 ' 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'我的驱动路径') 
driver.get(target_url) 
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//ul[@id="middle_avi"]/li[@wrapid="process_desc"]/a') 
button.click() 
page_text = driver.page_source tree = etree.HTML(page_text) 
p_list = tree.xpath('.//div[@class="proj_content"]/div[@class="content"]/p[@class="article "]')
for i in p_list:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
//div[@class='proj_content']/div[@class='content']/p[@class='article']
```

If this was not specific enough, you'd have to add further details.

Comment: I'm very grateful for your answer. But it didn't solve my problem. What I get is still an empty list. The url of the photo above is https://gongyi.qq.com/succor/detail.htm?id=12857. And my code is as follows. Could you help me see what's wrong?

Comment: Screenshots are not useful since probably nobody will retype the code to test it. Always post code snippets.

Comment: Edit your question and add it there.

Comment: I modified my post and attached  my code.